# program crashes when two bodies collide

Tags: javascript, p5.js, matter.js

I am making a slingshot game in p5.js using matter.js and I have come across an issue where the program and window crash every time two non static bodies collide.

When the program runs, the console displays the error message; `You just changed the value of "scale", which was a p5 function. This could cause problems later if you're not careful.`

What could this error message mean?

Comment: There's no way to help without a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're doing something like this:

```
scale = 42;
```

You shouldn't do this, because `scale` is already a function in P5.js.

I wouldn't think this would crash your whole browser though. Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem.